# Place text tightly above section header

Tags: sectioning

For a requirement specification I need to put some text right next to a requirement (a sentence or paragraph) for identification purposes. I would like to place such identifier right next to a section heading as well as shown below:

[image]

The example was created by using

```
\hfill\raisebox{10ex}[0pt][0pt]{{\emph{\scriptsize [LH_DTLTX_9]} }}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
```

right after the `\chapter` command, but this (obviously) leads to problems if the section heading needs more than a single line.

I have already checked several styles which provide customization of section headings, but was unable to find one which fits my needs. If I could customize the section heading, I would have to use two parameters, heading text and identifier string.

A better solution is to use the `reallynopagebreak` environment:

```
\begin{reallynopagebreak}
\hfill\raisebox{-14ex}[0pt][0pt]{{\emph{\scriptsize [LH_DTLTX_9]} }}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur elitr, sed}
\end{reallynopagebreak}
```

This attempt might affect the mechanism to put new section headings on a new page if the remaining vertical space at the page's bottom is too small.

Is there a more clean solution?

Comment: you can do this using `\titleline[r]{bla bla}` from [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)

Comment: @touhami: Could you elaborate? With package titlesec, I can control how a `\chapter{Foo}` will be typeset. But I would need to have an additional parameter to provide the ID as in `\chapter{Lorem ipsum...}`{LH_DTLX_9}`. I failed to see how this is possible.

Comment: First you need to definie a new command `\newcommand*\myDTLXcmd{}` next `\titleformat{\section}{\titleline[r]{\myDTLXcmd}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}` then you can use this `\renewcommand*\myDTLXcmd{....}\section{...}`
`

Answer (score 1):

To answer [the OP's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317379/place-text-tightly-above-section-header#comment775058_317379), what you can do is something like this

1. In `\titleline` define it to display `\myfavouritestring`.
2. Re-define the chapter command to take a second argument, and set `\myfavouritestring` accordingly. E.g.

   ```
    \newcommand\mychapter[2]{\renewcommand\myfavouritestring{#2} \chapter{#1}}
   ```
3. Remember in your preamble to define `\newcommand\myfavouritestring{}`.

---

### Example

Not quite exactly what you asked for, but because I have it in one of my files already prepped. You can modified the call to `titlesec`'s formatting functions to format as you want.

In the preamble we have

```
 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \newcommand*\listoftags{}
 \titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{\thesection}{.5em}{}%
     [\quad {\footnotesize (tagged as: \texttt{\listoftags})}]

 \newcommand\mysection[2]{\renewcommand\listoftags{#2}\section{#1}}
```

Running it with

```
 \mysection{Section title}{some tags, another tag} 
 Content
```

gives

[image]